# The overall deployment failed because too many individual instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I am creating CD with bitbucket and amazon ec2 code deploy

I am using this pipeline from Amazon[pipelines][1]

Here is  my codedeploy pipeline

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import sys
from time import strftime, sleep
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

VERSION_LABEL = strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
BUCKET_KEY = os.getenv('APPLICATION_NAME') + '/' + VERSION_LABEL + \
    '-bitbucket_builds.zip'

def upload_to_s3(artifact):
    """
    Uploads an artifact to Amazon S3
    """
    try:
        client = boto3.client('s3')
    except ClientError as err:
        print("Failed to create boto3 client.\n" + str(err))
        return False
    try:
        client.put_object(
            Body=open(artifact, 'rb'),
            Bucket=os.getenv('S3_BUCKET'),
            Key=BUCKET_KEY
        )
    except ClientError as err:
        print("Failed to upload artifact to S3.\n" + str(err))
        return False
    except IOError as err:
        print("Failed to access artifact.zip in this directory.\n" + str(err))
        return False
    return True

def deploy_new_revision():
    """
    Deploy a new application revision to AWS CodeDeploy Deployment Group
    """
    try:
        client = boto3.client('codedeploy')
    except ClientError as err:
        print("Failed to create boto3 client.\n" + str(err))
        return False

    try:
        response = client.create_deployment(
            applicationName=str(os.getenv('APPLICATION_NAME')),
            deploymentGroupName=str(os.getenv('DEPLOYMENT_GROUP_NAME')),
            revision={
                'revisionType': 'S3',
                's3Location': {
                    'bucket': os.getenv('S3_BUCKET'),
                    'key': BUCKET_KEY,
                    'bundleType': 'zip'
                }
            },
            deploymentConfigName=str(os.getenv('DEPLOYMENT_CONFIG')),
            description='New deployment from BitBucket',
            ignoreApplicationStopFailures=True
        )
    except ClientError as err:
        print("Failed to deploy application revision.\n" + str(err))
        return False     

    """
    Wait for deployment to complete
    """
    while 1:
        try:
            deploymentResponse = client.get_deployment(
                deploymentId=str(response['deploymentId'])
            )
            deploymentStatus=deploymentResponse['deploymentInfo']['status']
            if deploymentStatus == 'Succeeded':
                print ("Deployment Succeeded")
                return True
            elif (deploymentStatus == 'Failed') or (deploymentStatus == 'Stopped') :
                print ("Deployment Failed")
                return False
            elif (deploymentStatus == 'InProgress') or (deploymentStatus == 'Queued') or (deploymentStatus == 'Created'):
                continue
        except ClientError as err:
            print("Failed to deploy application revision.\n" + str(err))
            return False      
    return True

def main():
    if not upload_to_s3('/tmp/artifact.zip'):
        sys.exit(1)
    if not deploy_new_revision():
        sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Failed to deploy application revision.
An error occurred (ThrottlingException) when calling the GetDeployment operation (reached max retries: 4): Rate exceeded


  [1]: https://bitbucket.org/awslabs/amazon-ecs-bitbucket-pipelines-python/src/master/
```

When I push my changes  like this

```
git push
```

I get the following error:

```
The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are experiencing problems.
```

Comment: Are you sure you have correct IAM permissions set?

Comment: Yes am sure , problem is about HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS am trying to figure it out

Comment: Did any instances spin up? I just got this error, when I checked the code deploy agent log file on the instance, there is an error in it "Error during perform: RuntimeError - The deployment failed because a specified file already exists at this location:", so I would check if there are any errors in this log.